# Moving the windows of all open applications to pre-defined positions

Tags: wpf, uwp

Is it possible to use WPF, or UWP - or both - to move the windows of other open applications in Windows 10 (previous versions a bonus too)?

I'm on multiple monitors and when my computer wakes from sleep the application windows appear on random screens relative to where I left them. It's infuriating and I want to code up an app that puts them back on the correct screen.

This appears to have been a problem in Windows for 10 or 20 years and Microsoft apparently has zero interest in fixing it.

I can't find anything about how to do this in UWP or WPF in Google, I've searched for things like "UWP - moving other application windows" and just nothing remotely relevant comes up.

Is this possible - and if so can somebody point me in the right direction? (I'm an ASP.net developer so there would be a bit of a learning curve but happy to learn).

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the unmanaged Windows API to move windows. That's definitely possible in WPF. See the [`MoveWindow`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/MoveWindow.html) function.

Comment: Thanks - do you know if it's possible in UWP? Or does the sandbox prevent it?

Comment: It's impossible in UWP.